# How to access the last element of a split inside a PrintWriter?

Tags: java, java-stream, printwriter

I am trying to access the last element of my PrintWriter but am having trouble since I am using a pretty nested Stream. I am using a "," as a delimiter so any help would be appreciated.

```
if (!Files.exists(csvFile)) {
    try (Stream<String> dataLines = Files.lines(dataFile);
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(csvFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW))) {
        // Append the column headers
        writer.append(APPENDED_ATTR_COLS.concat("\n"));
        dataLines.map((line) -> line.split(DELIMITER))
                 .map((line) -> String.join(DELIMITER, line))
                 .forEach(writer::println);
        System.out.println(dataLines);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the last element of the split, you can update your `map` operation to:

```
.map(line -> {
        String[] split = line.split(DELIMITER);
        return split[split.length - 1];
    })
```

But, then there wouldn't really be any point in performing the `String.join` in the next map operation. So you might want to be looking out for something like:

```
String stringToWrite = dataLines.map(line -> {
    String[] split = line.split(DELIMITER);
    return split[split.length - 1]; // last word of split
}).collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER)); // join all such last words here 
writer.println(stringToWrite); // print the complete string
```

Comment: Since the delimiter is `","`, a simple `line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",")+1)` would do the same. But it’s not clear whether this is what the OP really wants.